# Сервис таймер блокировка экрана

Tags: android, android-studio, service

Есть сервис, в нем таймер, таймер каждую минуту обновляет запись в SQLite 
Если поставить тлф в блокировку таймер перестаёт работать(создал нотификатион на каждое срабатывание таймера, пока телефон заблокирован нотификатионы не всплывают) что делать??
Но если включить музыку и заблокировать то работает, или поставить на зарядку и заблокировать то работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем:
1. В манифесте написал:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

2.В сервисе:

```
      @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Healths");
    wl.acquire();
    PendingIntent pi = intent.getParcelableExtra("PendingIntent");
    timerTask = new mTimerTask(pi);
```

3.В таймере:

```
     class mTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Healths");
    ...<другие действия>
    @Override
    public void run() {
        wl.acquire();
   ...<другие действия>
```

В итоге сервис не замораживается при блокировке экрана.
Просто ОС сама глушит сервис при блокировке, так как хочет экономить заряд батареи, и способом, описанном выше можно запретить ОС'е глушить сервис. :)